# Visualizing MongoDB C# Linq query for Driver version 2.4

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I’m working with the 2.4 version of the C# Mongo Driver. I have found a lot of traffic on how to visualize (or explain) a query for previous versions or legacy C# Mongo Driver support. I’m not having any luck understanding how to see the native Mongo query behind my version 2.4 Linq.
In my specific case I am using PredicateBuilder to build a complex expression, which I then pass into the collection like this:

```
var s = collection.AsQueryable().Where(filter.Compile());
```

After that I can further refine the query as needed by adding skip, take, etc. Finally I can call .ToArray() and the query executes.

I have tried to enable “--profile 2 --slowms 15” on my Mongod instance, and I have verified that the profile level is 2 with db.getProfilingLevel(). I can clearly see logged queries when running adhoc queries via RoboMongo, or even when using the collection.find method from the c# Mongo 2.4 driver.

However, when I call .ToArray on my Linq query I cannot find the query sent to Mongo either though a logging method I know, or though some aspect of the c# driver itself.

If I instead rework my code to use BsonDocuments and the builder object, I can see the query – but I’d rather use Linq.

Can anyone help me to see the underlying query being sent to Mongo while using Linq and the Mongo 2.4 C# driver?

Relevant URL: 
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/linq/
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/reading/#aggregation

Notice for the 'reading section' there is a Note that explains you can call ToString on the pipeline to see what will be sent to the server. I can access the pipeline when using the BsonDocuments/Builder method of creating a query, but not when I use the Linq method.

**Update**: This seems to be related to filter.compile. If I don't use that, I can use .ToString() to view the query!

```
var sfilter = PredicateBuilder.True<MediaItem>();
var sTest = collection.AsQueryable().Where(sfilter.Compile()).Where(f => f.MediaItemType == MediaItemTypes.Image);
var sString = sTest.ToString();
// System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator'1[Common.Domain.MediaItem]

var xTest = collection.AsQueryable().Where(f => f.MediaItemType == MediaItemTypes.Image);
var xString = xTest.ToString();
// aggregate([{ "$match" : { "MediaItemType" : 1 } }])
```

The definition of PredicateBuilder.True:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>()
{
    return f => true;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't ``var query = collection.AsQueryable().Where(filter.Compile()).ToString();`` be the solution?

Comment: Hi Skami,
In this case when I call ToString() on my collection, in the way you have above, I get

`System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator'1[<MyType>]`

I am looking for the query that will be sent to Mongo.

Comment: @Skami that only works with Entity Framework LINQ providers.

Comment: @Adam P, that's odd. Whenever I run `var query = this.collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.id == 1).ToString();`  I get this as a result `aggregate([{ "$match" : { "_id" : 1 } }])`.

Comment: @Amy, [according to the source code itself that's not true](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/e7f872afc0b620d6540af70d8a0f6d7b25ee82bd/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/MongoQueryableEnumComparedToEnumTests.cs#L45).

Comment: @Skami Thanks for that link, I can clearly see I **should** be able to use .ToString()

Right now I am unsure why I can't. I am using v2.4 - not sure if that is related. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: @AdamP, maybe if you show a bit more code we could help you.

Comment: Was just getting that together, gonna update the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after reading your update I believe I may have found the solution to your problem.
Mongo has no overload for the compiled version of your predicate which returns a `Func<MediaItem, bool>`, however there is as expected an overload for [`[Expression<Func<MediaItem, bool>>`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/18d204a046373bdceb32f2e17030d3ca8fa12d59/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/MongoQueryable.cs#L2810).

So the following code should work for you.

```
var sfilter = PredicateBuilder.True<MediaItem>();
var sTest = collection.AsQueryable().Where(sfilter).Where(f => f.MediaItemType == MediaItemTypes.Image);
var sString = sTest.ToString();
```